# Koa - set timeout on incoming requests

Tags: node.js, settimeout, koa

I'm trying to set a timeout for incoming requests using a custom middleware, but no error is thrown, seems that the middleware is not called once `setTimeout` expires.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!ctx.headersSent) {
            ctx.throw(408, `processing time toke longer than ${config.PROCESSING_TIMEOUT}, request was timedout`);
        }
    }, config.PROCESSING_TIMEOUT);
    await next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koa (or rather node's http server) has a built-in way to control the timeout of requests.
A global timeout can be set by setting server's timeout in ms

```js
server.timeout = config.PROCESSING_TIMEOUT;
```

A timeout can be specified in a specific request for Koa as follows

```js
ctx.request.socket.setTimeout(config.PROCESSING_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: Will an error be thrown in such a case? Or will it just end the request?

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev Looks like it throws an ERR_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L606 which sends a 408 to the client https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L632

Comment: I set ctx.request.socket.setTimeout but now it does not generate the error, it moves to my error handler middleware, without throwing the ERR_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT error